# Log is showing no Error. still its running but map does not show near by places in Google Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, import

I am New in Android Studio and I want To ask that which API keys are mainly use while Setting the Keys in Manifest file and Main Activity file ?

My problem is when I Run the App it Working fine but when it comes to Find Near by places then on button click the map does not marked any thing on Android display Screen. I check the dependencies 
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'`

here is the manifest code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pc.myapplication" >

<permission
    android:name="com.example.pc.myapplication.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.javapapers.android.googleplacesdetail.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".GooglePlacesActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBoABE9sDCGOYNOzoKWchj6Dba4NUsgNu8" />
</application>
```

[I am Following this Tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/find-places-nearby-in-google-maps-using-google-places-apiandroid-app/#comment-159495)

Please Tell me what i am missing ... Thanks in Advance

Comment: Read this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: here is the manifest file code

Comment: i have update the code , Please Tell me if I am Missing something

Comment: yes it is the Api key